# Issue on angularJs $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

Tags: angularjs

I am learning AngularJs myself. Right now I am stuck on `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);`.

On `app.js` file I have used this code.

```
angular.module('ContactsApp', ['ngRoute'])
        .config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
                $routeProvider
                        .when('/contacts', {
                            controller: 'ListController',
                            templateUrl: 'views/list.html'
                        })

                $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

            }]);
```

On my window computer I have created virtual host using this code.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName contacts.local
    ServerAlias contacts.local
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot D:/xampp/htdocs/angularJs/contacts/public
    DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.htm
    <Directory "D:/xampp/htdocs/angularJs/contacts/public">
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
                Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Now issue is that when I try to open `http://contacts.local/#/contacts` that redirects to `http://contacts.local/contacts`. That is working fine.

But If I try to open `http://contacts.local/contacts` It shows me error **500 Internal Server Error**.

Please guide me where I have doing wrong. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AngularJS $locationProvider.html5mode(true) requires a server side rewrite to the root url to allow state links. You are trying to access a route directly, so none of the angular framework is being used, hence the 500 error.

Any route that does not match a configured route should be rewritten to hit your root url (i.e. index.html).

For example, you are using Apache, so to rewrite requests, you can use:

```
<Directory /path/to/app>
    RewriteEngine on

    # Don't rewrite files or directories
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
    RewriteRule ^ - [L]

    # Rewrite everything else to index.html to allow html5 state links
    RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]
</Directory>
```

See the FAQ https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-configure-your-server-to-work-with-html5mode

Answer (score 0):

You shall write route on server so that every request that does not match all other routes shall return your basic view (index.html for example). Rest routing will be done by angular. Detailed explanation:

When going to route `http://contacts.local/#/contacts` it is CHANGED to http://contacts.local/contacts without interacting with server, with [html5 history api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history)

When going directly to `http://contacts.local/contacts`, request has been made to server route `/contacts` that is not found